# How to get camera intrinsics through media foundation

Tags: directshow, ms-media-foundation, uvc

I'm trying to access the camera intrinsics parameters using media foundation \ directshow API's, like focal length, principal point and distortion coefficients.

I saw that focal length can be queried via ICameraControl, but for all the other parameters I can't find a way.

Is there a general way to do it in Media foundation\Directshow API's?

Answer (score 0):

[MediaCapture](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.Media.Devices.Core.CameraIntrinsics) on Windows 10 can get intrinsics information from some cameras. Intel RealSense, Windows Hello, and Kinect should be supported.

Also, intrinsics are available from the [MediaFrameSource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.media.capture.frames.mediaframesource), see [MediaCapture.FrameSources](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.media.capture.mediacapture).

[This UWP sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/bb447b0648f9b2c360f26efff7d312d7964a15a9/Samples/HolographicFaceTracking) can be used as a reference. You shouldn't have any problems with C# either.

Comment: yeah, I found UWP API's, was wondering if there's something in Win32.

Comment: @Eldar: UWP is supposedly obtaining that through Media Foundation. When intrinsics are available, you'd get the respective attributes with the captured video feed. I don't think you can access them with DirectShow though.

Comment: @Eldar, might be an off-topic, but you can use WinRT APIs from Win32 apps.

Comment: If you want to use MF APIs, you can get the binary blob from the IMFSample (it's MFStreamExtension_PinholeCameraIntrinsics defined in the mfapi.h), and then cast it to the MFPinholeCameraIntrinsics structure (mfapi.h). Devproxy's GetOutputStreamAttributes() result should have it too. I might be wrong, but the binary format for intrinsics is not standardized yet.